# 「型付き配列」という用語について

Tags: javascript

[JavaScriptの型付き配列](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) という用語が何を指すのか理解できないのですが、「型付き配列」とは下記の何れに該当するのでしょうか？

---

**a.バッファとビューで構成されている内容が、型付き配列**

> 型付き配列＝ バッファ(ArrayBufferオブジェクト) ＋ ビュー(TypedArrayオブジェクト)

---

**b.それとも、ビューの部分だけが型付き配列**
・型付き配列は、TypedArrayオブジェクトそのものを指す

> バッファ(ArrayBufferオブジェクト) ＋ ビュー(TypedArrayオブジェクト=型付き配列)

Comment: この書き方だと「リンク先に掲載されている用語」が何を指しているのかが一見して分かりづらいです(「型付き配列」であっていますか？)。また、「リンク先」や「このページ」などをリンクテキストとして設定すると、ページを開かないと何が書かれているかが分かりません。なるべく【意味のある文字列】(元ページのタイトル等)を設定することをお勧めします。

Comment: 改めて読み返してみると確かに分かりづらいですね。「型付き配列」のつもりで質問しました。リンクテキストについては「意味のある文字列」を明記するようにします

Answer (score 3, accepted):

原文を読んでみると

> A view provides a context that turns the data into typed array.
>   (view は data(buffer) を typed array に変換するするコンテキストを提供する)

とあるので、「a.バッファとビューで構成されている内容が、型付き配列」だと思います

- ArrayBuffer は typed array buffer であり、buffer の唯一の実装
- Int8Array, Uint8Array は typed array view の実装であり、広義には typed array でもある

という感じでしょうか

厳密には

- Int8Array が typed array view
- new Int8Array(2) が typed array

なのかもしれませんが、Int8Array は buffer と view を同時に提供する能力も持つので typed array と呼んでも問題ない場面は多そうです

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript の仕様書では、「Typed Array」は「`TypedArray` オブジェクト」のことを指します。小文字の「typed array」という用語は仕様書にはありません。

ですので、小文字の「typed array」が何を指すかというのは JavaScript 界隈で共通認識はなく、そのページをどう読むかという程度の問題です。